# Approximate search php oci

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I need make a search in php and oci using just prefixes of the terms, for example:

if the user type **bud** the result must contains all rows on the database that contains bud as part of the name. For exact terms my search is ok with the function:

```
function get_station_by_name($conn, $name, $skip = 0, $maxrows = -1){
    $statement = db_create_statement($conn, "SELECT id, name, city, avg_pass, min_pass FROM station WHERE name = :name");
    db_bind($statement, ':name', $name);
    return db_fetch_resultset($statement, $skip, $maxrows);
}

function db_bind($statement, $name, $value) {
    return oci_bind_by_name($statement, $name, $value);
}
```

I've search a lot how to do that, but I could not find very well results. 
I think I must include in my $name variable symbols like %,*.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$name = "bud";
$statement = "SELECT id, name, city, avg_pass, min_pass FROM station WHERE name LIKE :name";
db_bind($statement, ':name', "%" . $name . "%");
```

Looks for stations where the name contains "bud"
E.g buddingham or debudding